# Checking hosts file entry with PHP?

Tags: php, hosts-file

I'm creating a 'domain locking' script. Basically, the script will check my website to make sure that the host its running on is allowed to run it.

I don't want them to be able to modify their host file to reroute the connection.

Is there a way to check this and/or prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

You could also query the DNS server of the domain, and ask it the IP of the 'authorized' web server.

Comment: using : http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php or http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-dns.net-dns-resolver.query.php